# Getting the coordinates of GeoDisk[] and similar Mathematica 10 GeoObjects

Tags: graphics, geometry, geography, geodesy

I'm a big fan of the new Mathematica 10 geographic capabilities and functions such as GeoDisk[], GeoCircle[] and others. One limitation of these functions, however, is the transformation of the actual GeoGraphics primitives into a list of coordinates. For GeoDisk[] for instance I can always do this manually via functions such as:

```
Clear[genperimeter]
genperimeter[citypos_, radius_] := 
  Reverse@Normal@
      LatitudeLongitude[GeoDestination[citypos, {radius, #}]] & /@ 
   Most[Range[0, 360, 30]];
```

which simply calculates points spaced in 30 degree increments around the geographic circle. It would be much more convenient however to extract the perimeter coordinates directly from a GeoDisk[] object. I've spend some time looking through the documentation but have not found a solution.

Many thanks ahead of time for any tips.

Mac

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

Let's use a `GeoDisk[]` centered around the great city of Houston, TX:

```
houmap = GeoGraphics@
GeoDisk[CityData[{"Houston", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}, "Position"], Quantity[50, "Miles"]]
```

[image]

Now we can extract all the drawn polygons in the image:

```
Cases[houmap, Polygon[__], Infinity] // Length
```

> `3`

To verify which one we want:

```
Graphics/@ Cases[houmap, Polygon[__], Infinity]
```

[image]

So we want the last `Polygon`:

```
Cases[houmap, Polygon[__], Infinity][[-1, 1]]
```

> `{{-95.3863,32.0591},{-95.3571,32.0586},<<177>>,{-95.4156,32.0586},{-95.3863,32.0591}}`

These points, however, are x-y points, not the true latitude longitude of the `Disk`. To convert, we have write a function:

```
findcoordinates[geographic_, polylocation_] := Module[
{pts = Cases[geographic, Polygon[__], Infinity][[polylocation, 1]], proj, geomodel},
{proj, geomodel} = {GeoProjection, GeoModel} /. 
 AbsoluteOptions[geographic, {GeoProjection, GeoModel}];
(GeoPosition[GeoGridPosition[#1, proj, geomodel]] & /@ pts)[[All, 1]]
]
```

Now we can apply the function:

```
findcoordinates[houmap, -1]
```

> `{{30.5064,-95.3863},{30.5059,-95.3571},<<177>>,{30.5059,-95.4156},{30.5064,-95.3863}}`

We can verify by using a `GeoPath`:

```
GeoPath[findcoordinates[houmap, -1]] // GeoGraphics
```

[image]

Comment: You could just ask for `{GeoProjection, GeoModel} /. AbsoluteOptions[geographics, {GeoProjection, GeoModel}]` directly instead of tearing apart the coordinate display function.

Comment: @BrettChampion Man, that's way easier. Edit in progress...

Comment: Brilliant - many thanks. I'm wondering for cases whether the first two geographic objects will always be those related to the background display ? If this is true the object extraction process can be automated and findcoordinates[] will only require one parameter.

Comment: @Mac On the cases I tested, it was always third, but no promises.